# Java method returning blank array

Tags: arrays

I'm new to java and having trouble basically passing an array through to a method in another class, using the values to compute a new array, and then passing that back again to print. The problem is that when it prints the array it always prints the empty string. When I step through in debug mode I can see that the values are getting passed in and the array gets generated, but then when it prints it is always empty. It seems like somehow to code is failing to return the correct array maybe. Here is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  double[] rnoDivs;
  double[] rnoEarnings;

 Company rno = new Company();
        rnoDivs = new double[] {355, 355, 315, 240, 190};
        rno.yearlyDividendsGrowth(rnoDivs);
        rnoEarnings = new double[] {0.019, 3.451, 5.210, 3.543, 2.960};
        rno.yearlyEarningsGrowth(rnoEarnings);
```

This is passed through to my other class

```
public class Company {

double[] yearlyEarningsGrowth = {};
public double[] getYearlyEarningsGrowth(){return yearlyEarningsGrowth;}

    public double[] yearlyEarningsGrowth(double[] yearlyEarnings){
        double[] yearlyEarningsGrowth = new double[yearlyEarnings.length];
        for (int x = 0; x <= yearlyEarnings.length; x++) {
            if (x < yearlyEarnings.length - 1) {
                yearlyEarningsGrowth[x] = (yearlyEarnings[x] / yearlyEarnings[x + 1]) * 100;
            }
        }
            return yearlyEarningsGrowth;
    }
}
```

And then I try to print this statment

```
 Company[] companies = {rno};
for(int i=0; i < companies.length; i++) {
 double[] array = companies[i].getYearlyEarningsGrowth();
 System.out.println("Yearly earnings growth: " + Arrays.toString(array));
}
```

But then I just get the array "[]". Any help with this would be appreciated! I seem to be going in circles because everything looks correct.

Comment: You don't set yearlyEarningsGrowth to anything but the empty array. Why should it be something else?

Comment: I've been thinking about setters. The thing that I don't understand is that I have a bunch of other methods that very similar to the above method, the only difference being that they don't use an array (they just return a single value). These all work pefectly without a setter. So I don't really understand what the setter is doing - is it not sufficient to call the method and pass it an array?